# Upload de imagem para o webservice

Tags: ios, swift, restful, alamofire

estou utilizando o alamofire para fazer post pro servidor, queria saber como fazer para enviar uma objeto que possua uma img dentro dele.

vi o seguinte trecho para upload da imagem

```
  let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Default", withExtension: "png")
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", file: fileURL)
```

porem ainda nao consegui compreender como pegar o `fileURL`

Se alguém puder me informar se é possivel enviar um objeto completo com foto ou se tenho que envia de forma separada e como consigo o fileURL

Comment: Como assim você quer enviar um objeto com uma imagem dentro? Pode explicar isso melhor?

Comment: Aonde é que ta armazenada a sua imagem. Se voce fez o download provavelmente voce armazenou no documents directory. Se for o case voce precisa primeiro criar a url do documents directory e depois é só append o pathComponent a sua url (nome do arquivo).

Answer (score 0):

Em um projeto que fiz, leio o arquivo com `pathForResource`.

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Default", ofType:"png")
```